# How do I parse generic data types from a file?

Tags: c#, parsing, generics

I have a generic class as follows:

```
class myClass<T>
{
    public T[] m_SomeData;
}
```

I want to implement a generic method to read data from a file and populate the data fields of this class. Something like:

```
class myClass<T>
{
    public T[] m_SomeData;

    public void ReadData(string fileName);
}
```

An implementation of the ReadData methods looks something like this (all error checking removed for brevity):

```
void ReadData(string fileName)
{
   TextReader rdr = new StreamReader(fileName);

   string line = rdr.ReadLine();
   // Here I need to parse value of type T from the line
   // and initialize the m_SomeData array  
   // How do I do that? I would like to keep it generic if possible
}
```

Note, I can guarantee the type T is numeric, at least by convention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** OP would like human readable output.  I would suggest JavaScriptSerializer, then, in:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Web.Extensions.dll

```
// Serialize:
using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string s = serializer.Serialize(m_SomeData);                
    writer.Write(s);
}

// Deserialize:
using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(fs))
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var s = reader.ReadToEnd();
    m_SomeData = serializer.Deserialize<T[]>(s);                
}
```

---

**Old Answer:**
This is a job for [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx):

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open)) 
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    m_SomeData = (T[])formatter.Deserialize(fs);
}
```

This of course assumes you are also using it to serialize via `formatter.Serialize(fs, m_SomeData);`.

Comment: @Woll is correct.  However, I would do `using (var fs = new FileStream(...))` instead of try/finally.  Admittedly `using` is syntactic sugar for try/finally with a dispose, but it is accepted sugar.

Comment: Nice idea, but for debugging and test case purposes, I would like the file being parsed to be human readable/editable if possible. I am confident the generic types will be numeric, so string representations are possible for all anticipated types.

Comment: @Richard, good point; I had just lifted it directly from the MSDN manual, but agree your suggestion is more clear.

Comment: Thank you. Did you mean T[] instead of int[] in the penultimate line of Deserialize? And will the method work for entire parameterized classes?

Comment: @Andrew, whoops, yes, I did mean `T[]`.  What do you mean by "entire parameterized classes"?  You mean, like, not an `int`, but rather a complex object like a `Person`?  If so, yes, it will work fine.  However, it will not work if you have cyclic references.  (i.e. child elements in the object graph referring back to parent elements.)  Let me know if you  need to keep track of references.